# Navigate to next document without saving any changes in last document in AxWebBrowser

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, axwebbrowser

I am opening MS Office Document file in `AxWebBrowser` after that I navigate to next Office Document ,before navigating I saved the last document like this

```
AxWebBrowser1.ExecWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_SAVE, SHDocVw.OLECMDF.OLECMDF_ENABLED)
```

but how can I navigate to next Document without saving it even if it also have any changes?

if I do not use above line of code it ask for "`Save`",`"Don't Save"` and "`Cancel`" before navigating to next document.

help me thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could kill all Excel and Winword processes before opening the next:

```
    Try
        For Each prog As Process In Process.GetProcesses
            If prog.ProcessName = "EXCEL" Then prog.Kill()
            If prog.ProcessName = "WINWORD" Then prog.Kill()
        Next
    Catch
        err("Error Closing files")
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to reload the page first make sure to use reload and not refresh because refresh will only apply changes that aren't loaded.

Comment: as this isn't really an answer, it would be better as a comment.